Slice array using boolean values
Given a:
a = numpy.zeros(100, dtype=bool)
a[10:20] = True 
a[40:60] = True

I wish to slice an array b, also of length 100, into two arrays:
b[10:20], b[40:60]

In other words, I wish to establish the range of indexes in a containing True values, so that I can slice b into individual arrays.

Will there always be two true-segments?

And are you really given a, or can you work on the index ranges (0-20, 40-60) directly?

Let's rephrase the original problem as follows:

Split a one-dimensional array based on a boolean mask, so that each part corresponds to a sequence of continuous False or True mask values, and select only parts that correspond to True.

We can do it just like that with nonzero and diff:
def split_by_mask(arr, mask):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return []
    # mark starting points of each contiguous streak
    positions = np.diff(mask, prepend=mask[0]) 
    # get start indexes of contiguous streaks
    indexes = np.nonzero(positions)[0]
    # define the first position of True streaks
    first = not mask[0]
    # get streaks corresponding to True values
    return np.split(arr, indexes)[first::2]

Or as a one-liner:
np.split(b, *np.nonzero(np.diff(a, prepend=a[0])))[not a[0]::2]


p.s. Test cases to be sure it works:
from itertools import zip_longest

for case, arr, expected in [
    (1, np.array([]), []),
    (2, [1], [[1]]),
    (3, [0], []),
    (4, [1, 0], [[1]]),
    (5, [0, 1], [[1]]),
    (6, [1, 1], [[1, 1]]),
    (7, [0, 0], []),
    (8, [0, 1, 0], [[1]]),
    (9, [1, 0, 1], [[1], [1]]),
    (10, [1, 1, 0, 1], [[1, 1], [1]]),
    (11, [0, 0, 1, 0], [[1]]),
    (12, np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=bool), [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
]:
    try:
        assert all(np.array_equal(x, y) for x, y in zip_longest(split_by_mask(arr, arr), expected)), f'{case=}'
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(repr(e))


You can also do this:
a = np.zeros(100, dtype=bool)
a[10:20] = True
a[40:60] = True

b = np.arange(100)**2
b_indices = range(len(b))

 
slices_new = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(b_indices, lambda x: a[x] == True) if k]


for x in range(len(slices_new)):
    for y in range(len(slices_new[x])):
        slices_new[x][y] = b[slices_new[x][y]]

print(slices_new)

Output:
[[100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361],
 [1600,
  1681,
  1764,
  1849,
  1936,
  2025,
  2116,
  2209,
  2304,
  2401,
  2500,
  2601,
  2704,
  2809,
  2916,
  3025,
  3136,
  3249,
  3364,
  3481]]

